# How to add CC mail in MailChimp campaign

Tags: mailchimp, newsletter

I have a MailChimp pop-up campaign on my website which is working fine. When someone enters their information, they receive a welcome e-mail.

My question is: Can I add my e-mail address to cc/bcc so every time when someone subscribes to the list I receive a mail notification about the new subscriber.

Answer (score 0):

You can get notifications about it but it won't be in via the cc field. Mailchimp has its own notification system for you. Please see https://mailchimp.com/help/change-subscribe-and-unsubscribe-notifications/ :)